# Recieve variables in java Web Service from php cURL using POST?

Tags: java, php, curl

I'm recieving 'null' on my Params.
So far i've found people using "PathParams", "FormParams" and "QueryParams" on java to get their variables from the request, however in my case, using post i dont have PathParams, and for some reason FormParams and QueryParams are returning null as if i had never sent them. So i'd like help to solve this.

My php cURL POST request:

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost:8080/TestRest/test/asd";

$params = "param1=val1&param2=val2";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urlencode($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

My java Web Service:

```
@Path("/test")
public class Streams {

    @POST
    @Path("/asd")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
    public String addStream(@FormParam("param1") String param1, 
                        @FormParam("param2") String param2) {
    return "param1 = "+param1;
    }
}
```

For some reason param1 is null.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry about it, everything is good in the example above, problem was i was trying to receive one param as an 'int', must use Strings aparently. It made all params become null, weird stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am going out on a limb and saying your problem may stem from this:

```
urlencode($params);
```

For instance: `a=1&b=2&c=3` is perfectly valid.

`urlencode('a=1&b=2&c=3')` goes to this: `a%3D1%26b%3D2%26c%3D3` and your webservice may not understand what it is your are passing.  It is looking for `a=...&b=...&c=...` and you are not giving it any of that.

Try leaving off the `urlencode()` and seeing if it works.  If it does, and you still want to ensure content like `this&this` is encoded properly, then you will need to parse the url parameters, encode them, and then recombine them for the post data.

Comment: The variables keep being null, but it was helpful info.

Comment: If i take the urlencode() out Tomcat returns this: "Bad Request. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." and with it variables are null.